# How do I create a table whose values are based on queries of same table?

Tags: mysql, table

This is something that interests me, but I can't seem to find an answer as to how to do it.

Basically, if I have a table and I want a column of that table to be based on a query, particularly when that query is based on information that is inside the same table, how do I do that?

I don't have access to my SQL program right now, but I suspect it would look something like this:

```
{
     CREATE TABLE ABCD as ABCE
     (

          A int(11) default null,
          B int(11) default sum(ABCE.A)
     );
}
```

or something to that effect.

Am I way off base?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? You could use a materialized view there

Answer (score 3):

You are not off-base at all.  Actually pretty close.  In t-sql you can just use code like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sample2](
    [myIntColumn] [int] NULL,
    [myOtherIntColumn] [int] NOT NULL,
    [myBigIntColumn] AS ([myOtherIntColumn]+[myIntColumn])
)

GO

    INSERT INTO Sample2 VALUES (365,256),(10,25000), (1,2)

    SELECT * FROM Sample2

    --myIntColumn   myOtherIntColumn    myBigIntColumn
    --365           256                 621
    --10            25000               25010
    --1             2                   3
```

If you are looking for an aggregate as the default value, I do not believe you can do that simply.
To have an aggregate as a column in the a table, a view is a viable option, like so:

```
CREATE VIEW Sample3
AS 
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT SUM(myIntColumn) as mySUM
From Sample2 )
SELECT Sample2.*, CTE.mySUM FROM Sample2, CTE
GO

SELECT * FROM Sample3

--myIntColumn   myOtherIntColumn    myBigIntColumn  mySUM
--365           256                 621             376
--10            25000               25010           376
--1             2                   3               376
```

These queries assume your platform is MS SQL Server.

If your tag [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) was meant to only indicate the language, it would be helpful both for this question and future questions to tag with the platform.  For example, you could additionally tag as [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server).

Depending on your RBDMS and your requirements you might be able to leverage an indexed/materialized view.  This could additionally help performance, but there are some limitations on an [Indexed View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx) in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, the code that Thronk provided in his answer, will have to modified because of MySQL's limitations: there are no CTEs and views should have no derived tables:

```
create table abcd 
    (a int primary key,
     b int) ;
```

This will give an error:

```
create view sample2 
as 
    select abcd.a, abcd.b,
           s.mysum 
    from abcd 
      cross join 
        (select sum(b) as mysum from abcd) as s ;

> ERROR 1349 (HY000): View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause
```

A workaround is to not use a derived table but first join and then group by the table's PK:

```
create view sample3 
as 
    select abcd.a, abcd.b,
           sum(s.b) as mysum 
    from abcd 
      cross join abcd as s 
    group by abcd.a ;        -- the GROUP should be BY the table's PK
```

A simple test with:

```
insert into abcd 
  (a, b)
values 
  (1, 10), 
  (2,  7), 
  (3,  7),
  (4, 12) ;

select * from sample3 ;
```

will give you:

```
+---+------+-------+
| a | b    | mysum |
+---+------+-------+
| 1 |   10 |    36 |
| 2 |    7 |    36 |
| 3 |    7 |    36 |
| 4 |   12 |    36 |
+---+------+-------+
```

However, the above workaround will not be very efficient. Another approach, which will probably be much better is to define 2 views. One to calculate the aggregates (sum, avg, whatever) and then use the first view to define the second. Notice the similarity between views `sample5` below and the (failed attempt) `sample2` above:

```
create view sample4 
as 
    select sum(b) as mysum 
    from abcd ;

create view sample5 
as 
    select abcd.a, abcd.b,
           s.mysum 
    from abcd 
      cross join 
        sample4 as s ;
```